# Ссылка на fancybox из svg

Tags: javascript, svg, fancybox

Есть svg-файл со встроенными ссылками (`xlink:href="url"`). Он подключен через `<object>` к `index.html`, туда же подключены все необходимые для работы `Fancybox` скрипты. Проблема заключается в том, что `Fancybox` не хочет запускать модальное окно `iframe` с внешней страницей с ссылки svg-файла. При этом обычные html-ссылки `Fancybox` открывает нормально в том же файле.
Бьюсь целый день, пробовал менять скрипт, ничего не получается.
Вот этот скрипт работает с обычными ссылками, но не работает с ссылками из svg

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
          width: '70%',
          height: '100%' 
        });
      });
    </script>
```

Upd. Код для вставки svg:

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" class="svg" data="main.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
```

Код ссылки в svg-файле:

```html
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" xlink:href="iframe.html" ></a>
```

Fancybox не работает даже на ссылку внутри html, обрамленную в `<svg></svg>`

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста код svg файлов, где расположены ссылки и код  подключения svg файлов к  index.html, посредством `<object>` Постарайтесь не сокращать код, скопируйте как есть. Чтобы разобраться важна любая мелочь.

Comment: fancybox какой версии?

Comment: fancybox v.2.1.7

Comment: @Sergey в кодах, которые привели всё верно. Покажите код самого svg файла со ссылкой внутри него. Посмотрите ещё вот этот ответ по svg ссылкам. Может натолкнет на решение. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/722257/28748  .